# How to use the `-Xlog` option to generate `.log` file in IntelliJ plugin for ANTLR 4?

Tags: parsing, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, antlr4

I am using the ANTLR 4 plugin (version `1.20`; including ANTLR `4.11.1`) for IntelliJ. In [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/courses-at-nju-by-hfwei/2023-compilers-coding/blob/main/build.gradle) [in this project](https://github.com/courses-at-nju-by-hfwei/2023-compilers-coding/tree/main), I use the `-Xlog` option as follows:

```
generateGrammarSource {
    arguments += ["-Xlog", "-visitor"]
}
```

However, it does not generate `.log` file [as expected](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/tool-options.md#-xlog).